I have recently installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 on my laptop using Virtual Box 7.0.20 and I can't get the full screen mode activated
I was using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhVjgI57Ino&ab_channel=ProgrammingKnowledge to get it set up. For the most part, it works alright, but I can't seem to follow along with the Virtual Box Guest additions part, and I think the code might be slightly different for the versions I've downloaded. I've tried adjusting the "7.0.18" to "7.0.20" but it doesn't seem to work and I keep getting the same thing which is that "such a directory does not exist". I am very new to this and I'm sure the solution is very simple, but I can't figure it out. Please help.

Your post is confusing. What does a nonexistent directory have to do with full screen mode? Please edit your post to focus on one single problem you are having. You never mention full screen mode except in the title. Also, no one is going to watch a video to see what you attempted to do, you need to tell us.
